# Connect to a tomcat via a nodejs application

Tags: node.js, tomcat

I created a nodejs application to test whether the web applications are still running and was wondering if there is a way to connect to the specific tomcat to restart it if ever it's down. 
I tried to google it, but the only things that would come up is setting up a node application on tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do the monitoring through a node app, there are paid and free frameworks to do this very effectively including email alerts, text message and even phone calls. newrelic, Sentry and Site24X7 to name a few, however if you want to monitor through nodejs, can't you just check the main url with something like this? BTW you need request NPM for this example 
npm install request

```
var request = require('request');
// Check every 30 seconds
var INTERVAL = 30;

var payload = {
    // Edit to whatever tomcat URL you want to check periodically
    url: 'http://localhost:8000',
    //url: 'http://www.google.com',
    method: 'GET'
}

setInterval(function() {
    request(payload, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            // DO something with the error,like email, text or phone call
            console.err(err);
        } else {
            if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                // Error DO something with the error,like email, text or phone call
                console.log('Error ....');
                console.log(response.statusCode);
            } else {
                console.log('Server working okay');
            }
        }

    });

}, INTERVAL * 1000);
```